# How to solve time complexity of T(n) = 9T(n/3) + 2n^2 + n/3 using master method?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, master-theorem

I can't able to figure out what f(n) is ? Is it n^2 or 2n^2 + n/3 ? How to solve such questions ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer science principles, not programming problems, algorithms, or tools used by software developers.

Answer (score 0):

Recalling the master theorem as follows: given the recusion equation

```
T(n) = b*T(n/c) + f(n),
```

it holds for `E = log(b)/log(c)`:

1. if `f(n)` is in `O(N^(E - eps))` for some `eps > 0`, then `T(n)` is in `Theta(n^E)`;
2. if `f(n)` is in `Theta(N^E)`, then `T(n)` is in `Theta(N^E * log(n))`;
3. if `f(n)` is in `Omega(N^(E + eps))` for some `eps > 0` and additionally `b*f(n/c) <= d*f(n)` for some `d < 1` and `n` big enough, then `T(n)` is in `Theta(f(n))`.

Otherwise, the master theorem does not help you. (You can get this definition from every basic textbook on algorithms, or using Google.)

From you definition, we have `b = 9` and `c = 3` and `f(n) = 2*n^2 + n/3`. So it is easily shown that case 2 holds as `E = 2` and `f(n)` is in `Theta(n^2)`. Therefore, `T(n)` is in `Theta(n^2 * log(n))`.